# Android getLocationOnScreen returns wrong and negative values

Tags: android

I have a custom view which I can successfully drag around the screen by touching it and dragging it, using `onTouchEvent` in the custom view. I added the custom view in a fragment's `onCreateView` with `binding.getRoot().addView(customView)`.

Now in my `onTouchEvent`, when I get `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to signal the end of the drag, I'm trying to determine the custom view's position on the screen.

My code is

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    int[] loc= new int[2];
    getLocationOnScreen(loc);
...
```

When I print out `loc[0]` and `loc[1]`, they don't correspond to the location of the view on the screen. In fact, I get negative values like -319,695, which appear to be nonsense as I can see the custom view on the screen, so how can the X location be negative? How can I get the custom view's location on the screen?

Comment: Enable the possibility to show "Layout limits" for Development Options and watch how big that View is.

Comment: @emandt Great suggestion - I'm not at my PC right now but you made me realise my view is much bigger than I thought it was. Thanks!